# In Onelogin, Can SCIM provisioning be used with OIDC app?

Tags: openid-connect, onelogin, scim

I've OIDC enabled a webapp and I am linking the users via email in the id_token. We have decided to use OIDC because it seemed newer and simpler to use. Now we need to implement `SCIM with OIDC SSO`; but when I search `OneLogin > add apps`, there seems to be only variations of `SCIM Provisioner with SAML`. Is it possible to use `SCIM with OIDC` or do I have to SAML enable the webapp.

`SCIM` specification doesn't seem to be dependent on SAML by itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SCIM Provisioner with SAML` (and possibly other connectors) can be used for provisioning without filling `SAML` related fields. Therefore, it is possible to use two separate connectors, one for the `OIDC` connection and the other for the `SCIM` provisioning. Onelogin doesn't support a `SCIM provisioning with OIDC` type connector currently.